# How can I make tastypie filter on a foreign field?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two models like this:

```
class CompanyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Company.objects.all()
        fields = ['title', 'latitude', 'longitude']
        resource_name = 'company'
        filtering = {
            'latitude': ALL,
            'longitude': ALL
        }

class EventResource(ModelResource):
    company = fields.ToOneField(CompanyResource, 'company', full=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ['title', 'company']
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'event'
        filtering = {
            'company': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

Then I try to access `/api/v1/event/?format=json&company_latitude__within=2,3` or `/api/v1/event/?format=json&company_latitude__lt=1` it isn't filtered on latitude:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20, 
        "next": "/api/v1/event/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json", 
        "offset": 0, 
        "previous": null, 
        "total_count": 329
    }, 
    "objects": [
        {
            "company": {
                "latitude": "1.30521100000000", 
                "longitude": "103.81116299999996", 
                "resource_uri": ""
            }, 
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/event/16/", 
            "title": "50% off at Infusion@Dempsey, $50 for $100 worth of Fine Dining"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh it's because of two things. I can't do `field__within` in Django (why did I think that?) and it should've been `/api/v1/event/?format=json&company__latitude__lt=2`.

Comment: so it's double underscore to do a join by the foreign key. Goodie!